# How to run "firefox -profilemanager" with Unity?

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher, unity-dash, settings

I'm trying to find a way to edit the command that runs Firefox to just add "-profilemanager" to it, but can't find anyway on how to do it on Unity launcher or dash.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have no running instance of firefox.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

[image]

Just enter your command as shown.